# Why is `docker/compose` Docker image stuck at 1.29.2?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using the [docker/compose](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose/tags) image, and things are running fine.

It just feels awkward that the page says "Updated a year ago".

Has the Docker Compose (on Docker) development moved somewhere else? What should I know?

Comment: It sounds like that image simply isn't maintained. I imagine that's partly because compose is generally run on the docker host; using it from inside a container is probably a bit of an edge case.

Comment: @larsks You are right. This is likely due to transitioning to "docker compose" (no dash). My use case is running Docker Compose within Cloud Build.